# Android calanderview Go to Today button

Tags: android, xml, button, android-calendar, calendarview

I have a CalanderView and a Button. I need to program the button to point to today's date when clicked. Help please!

**activity_calendar_view.xml:**

```
<CalendarView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Today"
    android:id="@+id/btToday"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

**CalendarView.java:**

```
public class CalendarView extends ActionBarActivity {

Button btToday;
Calendar calendar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar_view);

    btToday = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btToday);
    btToday.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

private View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong, the `CalendarView` is already set to the today date. In your case, I guess, you can set to the `CalendarView` today date by follow.

```
btToday.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                             @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                               mCalendarView.setDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), false, true);
                             }
                           }
```

Comment: I cannot .setDate to me CalendarView

Comment: @Sugan Have you created a `CalenderView` object and set it to `R.id.calendar` ?

Comment: Yes I tried, but I get the Inconvertible Types error when I do

Comment: I figured it out! It was because my Activity name was similar and I choose the wrong `CalenderView` when IntelliSense suggested. The code works, thanks!